# Why does Scala require pattern variables to be linear?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Scala requires pattern variables to be linear, i.e. pattern
variable may not occur more than once in a pattern. Thus, this example does not compile:

```
def tupleTest(tuple: (Int, Int)) = tuple match {
  case (a, a) => a
  case _ => -1
}
```

But you can use two pattern variables and a guard to check equality instead:

```
def tupleTest(tuple: (Int, Int)) = tuple match {
  case (a, b) if a == b => a
  case _ => -1
}
```

So why does Scala require pattern variables to be linear? Are there any cases that can not be transformed like this?

## Edit

It is easy to transform the first example into the second (Scala to Scala). Of all occurrences of a variable `v` in the pattern take the expressions that is evaluated first and assign it to the variable `v`. For each other occurrence introduce a new variable with a name that is not used in the current scope. For each of those variables `v'` add a guard `v == v'`. It is the same way a programmer would go (=> same efficiency). Is there any problem with this approach? I'd like to see an example that can not be transformed like this.

Comment: Such a pattern matcher would be substantially more difficult to specify and implement.

Comment: What would the advantage be of using `a` twice, in your first example? Isn't it clearer to refer to `case (a, b)` where `a` and `b` are different names? Also, is `linear` a term of compilers? `Unique` seems to be a better word, but I don't have any compiler theory background.

Comment: The example is not well chosen, but it is simple and shows the meaning of the term `linear`, which is used in a lecture of my university. My teacher could not answer this question. Thus, I hope that the community can help.

Comment: @SethTisue Why is it difficult? How about the approach described in my question (see edit)?

Comment: It's a good question, but it's not really on-topic for SO. I'd suggest http://cs.stackexchange.com or the Scala mailing lists

Answer (score 0):

Because `case (a, b)` is basically assigning `val a` to `_._1` and `val b` to `_._2` (at least you can view it like that). In case of `case (a, a)`, you cannot assign `val a` to both `_._1` and `_._2`.

Actually the thing you want to do would have been looked like

```
case (a, `a`) => ???
```

as scala uses backtick to match an identifier. But unfortunately that still doesn't work as the visibility of `a` is given only after `=>` (would have been fun though, I also hate writing `case (a, b) if a = b =>`). And the reason of this is probably just because it is harder to write a compiler that supports that

Comment: "to match a literal" In this case a is not literal. Literal is "a" or 0, a is an identifier from an outer scope. (The confusion probably comes from identifier in backticks being called literal identifier).

Comment: @Suma You are surely correct, thanks. I have fixed the answer

Comment: See my edit. I would introduce `case (a, a)` as syntactic sugar for `case (a, b) if a == b`. I describe in my edited question how to generate this code automatically. Is this approach not well thought out?

Comment: @MegaMuetzenMike I don't think `case (a, a)` makes any sense. You think of case as the same expression as any other expression in scala, but it is not. `case (a, _)` have very special meaning of `a` being assigned to the object that was behind the pattern. You can't just write `case (a, a)` and expect first `a` and second `a` behave differently. In scala you can compare something in the pattern match only by 1) `if` 2) backtick notation 3) having the variable starting with uppercase, this is how specification defines that and you propose just to change everything there

Comment: @MegaMuetzenMike You could always start a discussion of proposal to change things, there are mail-lists in scala dev team just for that. SO is not the place for such things. Another way to do that is to write a scala macro for that, but I am not sure it is easy to achive given the very special meaning of pattern matches in scala